# Como obter posição de uma sub-lista dentro de outra lista?

Tags: c#, .net, lista

Tenho uma lista de bytes e preciso verificar se ela contém uma sub-lista de bytes em uma ordem específica.

Como posso fazer essa verificação obtendo a posição da sub-lista de uma maneira simples, usando os recursos do `Linq` ou da própria `List`, ou seja, sem a necessidade de ter que fazer um `for` verificando posição a posição.

Exemplificando:

```
List<byte> bytes = new List<byte> { 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80  };
List<byte> pattern = new List<byte> { 30, 40, 50 };

int indiceInicioSublista = ???
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode aninhar dois loops para fazer isso: para cada posição válida da lista principal, verificar se cada item da lista sendo buscada bate. Se chegar até o final sem achar, então retorna um valor negativo, indicando que não achou.

***A versão LINQ, equivalente está no final da resposta.***

```
public static int FindSubList<T>(IList<T> mainList, IList<T> subList)
{
    for (int it = 0; it <= mainList.Count - subList.Count; it++)
    {
        bool allEquals = true;
        for (int it2 = 0; it2 < subList.Count; it2++)
        {
            if (!mainList[it + it2].Equals(subList[it2]))
            {
                allEquals = false;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (allEquals)
            return it;
    }

    return -1;
}
```

Usando o **LINQ** ficaria assim, que é o equivalente ao código acima:

```
public static int FindSubList<T>(IList<T> mainList, IList<T> subList)
{
    for (int it = 0; it <= mainList.Count - subList.Count; it++)
        if (!subList.Where((t, it2) => !mainList[it + it2].Equals(t)).Any())
            return it;

    return -1;
}
```

Outra alternativa usando LINQ sobre `IEnumerable`, entretanto essa solução é mais lenta do que a de cima:

```
public static int FindSubEnumerable<T>(IEnumerable<T> mainList, IEnumerable<T> subList)
{
    return
        Enumerable.Range(1, mainList.Count())
            .FirstOrDefault(it => mainList.Skip(it - 1).Take(subList.Count()).SequenceEqual(subList)) - 1;
}
```

Comment: Obrigado, mas estou procurando uma versão mais simples sem usar for. Usando for eu já consegui fazer.

Comment: Eu indiquei uma solução LINQ! Está no final da resposta.

Comment: Agora eu indiquei outra alternativa, usando LINQ puro, sobre `IEnumerable` ao invés de listas.

Comment: A versão com `IEnumerable` é mais lenta, eu recomendo a segunda solução, que é usando LINQ sobre `IList`.

Comment: @MiguelAngelo no código seu não deveria ser <byte> em vez de <int> ?

Comment: @FCCDias: Realmente! Fiz os códigos ficarem genéricos de forma que qualquer tipo de dados seja suportado.

Comment: A versão LINQ com IList ainda está com problemas, vou arrumar isso.

Comment: Testei a última opção, e funcionou corretamente. Obrigado.

Comment: Corrigido, ao converter para genérico, inverti sem querer a condição de teste.

Answer (score 1):

Pega a igualdade de elementos independente da posição.

```
List<byte> result = bytes.Where(e => pattern.Contains(e)).ToList<byte>();
IEnumerable<byte> result1 = bytes.Intersect(pattern);
IList<byte> result3 = bytes.Intersect(pattern).ToList<Byte>();
```

---

Retornar true, se `bytes` estiver dentro de `pattern`, que foram convertidos em String.

```
bool retorno = String.Join("", bytes).Contains(string.Join("", pattern));
```

***Referências***

1 - [Getting Started with LINQ in C#](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/bb397933.aspx)

2 - [101 LINQ Samples](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/101-LINQ-Samples-3fb9811b)

Comment: Dessa forma, mesmo que o pattern mude, ele continuar trazendo o resultado. A ordem do pattern é importante.

Comment: Então, @RenatoDinhaniConceição, no caso ele vai trazer os elementos que se repete independente da ordem !!! é isso !!! ou entendi errado

Comment: Então, na verdade, a ordem é importante sim.

Comment: O pattern é um cabeçalho de um protocolo, e quando ele é encontrado, todo o conteúdo depois dele tem um significado diferente.

Comment: Mude o pattern para `{ 30, 50, 40 }`. Não é pra retornar nada.

Comment: Caro @RenatoDinhaniConceição, porque, você não forneceu isso na pergunta, que os dados tem sequencia ?

Comment: Primeira linha da pergunta: "se ela contém uma sub-lista de bytes em uma ordem específica."

Comment: @RenatoDinhaniConceição isso não ta claro